# How can a docker container listen to all docker events?

Tags: docker

I want to listen to docker events from within a separate docker container, but it is failing an I'm guessing it's because it doesn't have access to the events.

Is there any (simple) way of listening to all docker events from inside a docker container?

I'm using node and the code is working fine (works perfectly on local machine) so I don't think this is really a node question. It has to be related to docker I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can share the Docker controlling socket with `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`, as shown [here](https://github.com/gliderlabs/registrator) for instance. However, there are some [caveats](https://www.lvh.io/posts/dont-expose-the-docker-socket-not-even-to-a-container.html): basically, doing this effectively grants full administrator access to the target container.